# read binary file using javascript and display in a html page

Tags: javascript, html, binaryfiles

I created a binary file with some records using 'C' Language. Now i want to display the binary file contents to my HTML page using Javascript or some other language. How can i display Binary file content in HTML page?

Comment: why would you want to do that in the first place.. ?

Comment: using the binary file(which has student records) as backend.. now I need to display the contents in my web page designed in HTML.. how can I link the binary file to web page.. which language will be preferable?

Comment: You need to tell us about the context: where are those files ? on the server or the client ? What do you expect the browser to do ? The result will probably be a mess of special chars...

Comment: The binary files contain the student records. The file can be in the server/client. The browser has to read those files and display the records

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend against doing this. Even if you could find a reliable manner in which to do this with JavaScript it may drastically reduce performance for the user because you have no control over how fast their computer is or the browser they are using.

JavaScript is being used for rendering more and more but not for conversion of binary data and then rendering it.

If you are concerned with having to spin up a large server side application use a simple PHP page or CSHTML WebMatrix page to convert the data before returning it to the client. You can pull this off relatively easily and you will save your self a lot of time in the end.

Comment: give this a shot http://psoug.org/snippet/PHP-Binary-to-Text-Text-to-Binary_380.htm